# How to use variable in xcopy since source file name is dynamic?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

For example I have

```
xcopy "C:\windows\match\goal.cfg" "c:\Program Files\Gate\" /e /i /h /r /k /y
```

where the name of the folder **match** is dynamic and always changes. How can I variablize the path directly to point a file in match folder to copy to gate folder in program files?

Comment: Where does the value of _match_ comes from?

Comment: Since the question is kind of vague, a quick & dirty method would be to simply replace \match\ with \\*\, but that makes a lot of assumptions (like it's a single directory you're copying from, not multiples which would overwrite `goal.cfg` until the last copy).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass a folder name variable into the batch file you could use:

```
@echo off
set /p "folder=Enter folder name: "

xcopy "C:\windows\%folder%\goal.cfg" "c:\Program Files\Gate\" /e /i /h /r /k /y
```

Comment: +1 Edited to allow for foldernames with & etc and the moved quote removes the need for `%=%`